# I need to determine the velocity change that allows for an orbital rendezvous between two orbiting spacecraft

Tags: fortran, gnuplot, runge-kutta, orbital-mechanics

I need to perform an exercise with Fortran90 that has as its objective what is written in the title. I have a starting system formed by second degree equations with certain boundary conditions. I transformed the system to have equivalent first degree equations in order to integrate it, and then it was dimensionalized obtaining : dx/dt= vx; d(vx)/dt=-1; dy/dt= vy; d(vy)/dt=-1 with the following boundary conditions x(0)=1; y(0)=0; y(t)=0; x(t)=-1 with t=1.

Now I solve with the method of shooting and RK4 with the initial conditions so chosen: x(0)=1; y(0)=0; vx(0)=0; vy(0)=v1+Δv. Being a nonlinear system I have to iterate until convergence, the rendezvous is considered successfully completed at time t when the two vehicles are within 3 m, i.e. the set tolerance, to be dimensionalized. I report my code below:

```
SUBROUTINE dydx(neq, x, y, f)

INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: neq
REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: x
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq), INTENT(IN) :: y !y=(y1,y2)=(1,v)
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq),INTENT(OUT) :: f

!y 1 componente y, 2 componente v
f(1) = y(2)   !dx/dt=v
f(2) = -y(1)  !dv/dt=-1

END SUBROUTINE dydx

SUBROUTINE RK4(neq, h, x, yold, ynew)
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: neq
REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: h, x
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq), INTENT(IN) :: yold
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq), INTENT(OUT) :: ynew
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq) :: k1, k2, k3, k4
INTEGER :: i

CALL dydx(neq, x, yold, k1)

DO i=1, neq
  ynew(i) = yold(i) + 0.5d0*h*k1(i)
END DO

CALL dydx(neq, x + 0.5d0*h, ynew, k2)

DO i=1, neq
  ynew(i) = yold(i) + 0.5d0*h*k2(i)
END DO

CALL dydx(neq, x + 0.5d0*h, ynew, k3)

DO i=1, neq
  ynew(i) = yold(i) + h*k3(i)
END DO

CALL dydx(neq, x + h, ynew, k4)

DO i=1, neq
  ynew(i) = yold(i) + h*(k1(i) + 2.0d0*k2(i) + 2.0d0*k3(i) + k4(i)) / 6.0d0 
END DO

END SUBROUTINE RK4

SUBROUTINE save_results(fname, neq, npoints, x, y)!!!!!risultati da salvare
CHARACTER (len=*), INTENT(IN) :: fname
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: npoints, neq
REAL*8, DIMENSION(0:npoints), INTENT(IN) :: x
REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq, 0:npoints), INTENT(IN) :: y

INTEGER :: i,j

OPEN(40, FILE=fname)

DO i=0, npoints
  WRITE(40,'(5(1pe20.12))') x(i), (y(j,i), j=1, neq) !!!!!!
END DO

CLOSE(40)

END SUBROUTINE save_results




PROGRAM secondo

 IMPLICIT NONE

 INTEGER, PARAMETER :: npoints = 1000
 INTEGER, PARAMETER :: neq = 4
 INTEGER :: i, toll
 REAL*8, DIMENSION(0:npoints) :: x
  REAL*8, DIMENSION(neq,0:npoints) :: y
 REAL*8 :: h, xmin, xmax
 REAL*8 :: w1, w2, w3, y1, y2, yn, xn

 !shooting
  !condizioni al contorno
 xmin = 0.0d0 !t0=0
 xmax = 1.0d0 !t_rv=1
 xn=-1.0d0
 yn= 0.0d0

   h = (xmax - xmin) / npoints


DO i=0, npoints
  x(i) = xmin + i*h
END DO

 !condizioni iniziali
 y(1,0) = 1.0d0 !x(0)
 y(2,0) = 0.0d0 !y(0)
 y(3,0) = 0.0d0 !vx
 y(4,0) = 0.5d0!vy
 w1 = y(4,0)

 DO i=1, npoints
    CALL RK4(neq, h, x(i), y(:,i-1), y(:,i))
 END DO

 y1 = y(1,npoints)

 CALL save_results('risultati_prima_iter.txt', neq, npoints, x, y)

 y(1,0) = 1.0d0 !x(0)
 y(2,0) = 0.0d0 !y(0)
 y(3,0) = 0.0d0 !vx
 y(4,0) = 2.0d0 !vy
 w2 = y(4,0)

 DO i=1, npoints
     CALL RK4(neq, h, x(i), y(:,i-1), y(:,i))
 END DO

 y2 = y(1,npoints)

 CALL save_results('risultati_seconda_iter.txt', neq, npoints, x, y)

  w3 =  w2 + (w2 -w1) / (y2 -y1) * (yn - y2)

  !!!!!convergenza
  toll=1.d-12


 DO i=1, npoints
    DO WHILE (ABS(yn-y2)<=toll)
       CALL RK4(neq, h, x(i), y(:,i-1), y(:,i))
       w2=w3
     END DO
     CALL save_results('risultati_terza_iter.txt', neq, npoints, x, y) 
  END DO

END PROGRAM secondo
```

At this point, if the code is correct, I should have found the value of Δv searched (in m/s) but I can not understand which column of the file "results_third_iter.txt" gives me the calculated result.
In fact the next step is to make two graphs with gnuplot: the first with the trajectory of vehicle 1 in time, the second with the distance from the earth's surface of vehicle 1, as a function of time (distances in km, time in minutes) but even here I can not get sensible results.

Which data column in the file should I use to plot the graph? Also I think there is some error in the code because if I plot the three files at the same time without specifying the data columns to use, I get three identical parabolas which should not be so, where am I wrong?

Thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran uestions, Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard. Be aware that `REAL*8` is not standard Fortran 90, or any other Fortran, syntax, even if widely supported as a non-standard extension.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How does this work? In the upper code you have encoded the 2D circle motion with constant angular speed 1, in the second code you seem to use a system with 4 components, as also described in the text. Nowhere are the gravity equations to be found.

Comment: Hi Bartim, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Your question appears to contain several questions in one, and so is unlikely to get answered. If you want to ask about gnuplot, please do so in a separate question, providing your data file (or a minimal example thereof if it's big) and the gnuplot commands you have tried. If instead you want Fortran help, please identify which part of your code is in error. You can do this using `print` statements, or better yet by using a debugger or unit tests.

Comment: Having said that, the first thing that leaps out at me is your loop `DO WHILE (ABS(yn-y2)<=toll)`. Since none of `yn`, `y2` and `toll` are varied within this loop, I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Also, in `dydx`, the array `f` contains `neq=4` elements, but you're only setting the first two. Since `f` is `intent(out)`, the last two elements will be uninitialised, but you are using these elements in `rk4`.

Comment: Also, you're passing a variety of values to the `x` argument of `dydx`, but `dydx` doesn't use `x`. You can catch this kind of problem using your compiler's warning flags. Such flags also point out that you have defined `toll` to be an integer, and are then trying to initialise it to `1.d-12`.